# Word for alcoholic or nonalcoholic drinks or smokes that guests might bring to a party

Tags: single-word-requests

I’m hosting a party and a guest asked if they could bring anything.  I want them to bring whatever they’ll enjoy drinking (alcoholic or not) or smoking, but don’t want them to particularly go out of their way for me.  What word (or other phrasing) conveys this without setting extra expectations? I’d like to use a phrase like, “please bring your ______ of choice”, but am also open to other phrases.

- “refreshments” is general enough to cover all three categories, but also sometimes means light food or snacks, which I don’t want to imply
- “Inebriations” doesn’t include my sober friends
- “Drinks” doesn’t suggest that there may be people smoking/vaping

Comment: Doesn't BYOB cover CBD by now?

Comment: In my experience, people who smoke will bring their smokes with them, whether you invite them to or not.

Comment: Another option is "Please bring whatever you like."

Comment: If the expected word relates to alcohol, soft drinks, tobacco but excludes food., then  "Please bring the goodies of your choice" will not match, as almost all suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the somewhat ironic

> Please bring your ***poisons*** of choice.

[Green's Dictionary of Slang](https://greensdictofslang.com/search/basic?q=poison) gives this as its first meaning:

> **poison**, n.
>
> 1. an ironic term for drink in general.
> 2. in senses of someone or something harmful. (4 subsenses)
> 3. in drug uses. (4 subsenses)

I don't think this would exclude your sober friends if they have a sense of humour – after all, it *is* a party. It might even suggest a sub-text in the minds of some: leave your real poisons behind.

Comment: @Cascabel_StandWithUkraine_ in BrE we have [What's your poison?](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/whats-your-poison).

Comment: Shiraz or Malbec for me please, but not from North America. I find their wines overly sweet and cloy the palate after the first one.

Comment: In the same ironic vein, one may say "please bring anything we need to satisfy our addictions".